# How to make fixed position div relative to its parent div instead of browser window?

Tags: html, fixed

I want to make something like this
[here is the example sidebar](http://www.bootply.com/82265)

i have a div center aligned with fixed width 1280px and margin 0 auto.
under it i want to have a fixed position div aligned at left relative to its parent div (under 1280px div left)

but now my fixed position div is touching browser windows edge.

```css
.sidelinks-lft {width:1280px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}
.sidelinks-lft .sidelinks {width:200px; position:fixed; left:0; z-index:4; ;  top:0; }
```

```html
<div class="sidelinks-lft">
<div class="sidelinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#multisensory">multisensory</a></li>
<li><a href="#vvc">vvc</a></li>
<li><a href="#mCues">mCues</a></li>
<li><a href="#ergonomics">ergonomics</a></li>
<li><a href="#testing">testing</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use position **absolute** for child div .
in css

```
.sidelinks-lft {width:1280px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}
.sidelinks-lft .sidelinks {width:200px; position:absolute; left:0; z-index:4; ;top:0; }
```